# This application does not profiled with JProfiler

Tags: java, jprofiler

IDE: Intellij IDEA 11.1.2
jProfiler: v.7.1.2

OS: Windows 7 32-bit

jProfiler integrated into IDEA.
Java-console program is invoked with VM:-server or -Xshare: off.

Total:

After clicking on Profile '[name]' or Attach to JVM - opens jProfiler with inactive buttons in the left menu and start the program with no results.

If you create a session using the Session -> New Session -> Application Setting -> tab "Profiled JVM" -> Attach -> choose "Select from all local JVMs", then press the OK button and select from the list of "idea.exe", you get an error:

"Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8849. Please make sure that the remote address is correct, the remote program is started properly and the network route allows socket connections"

Can you please tell how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved.

The reason for the problem:

In the firewall was disabled to carry out program activities such as "Out" for protocol "TCP & UDP"